# Create wrapper class for map implementation

Tags: xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

Im trying to create a wrapper to hold google and huawei maps implementation.
Right now my classes implement both huawei and google.
What can i do to split the implementation? Im a bit lost how to do this.

```
public class Marker
{

    public Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker Google { get; set; }

    public Huawei.Hms.Maps.Model.Marker Huawei { get; set; }

    Marker(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.Marker google, Huawei.Hms.Maps.Model.Marker huawei)
    {
        Google = google;
        Huawei = huawei;
    }

    public void setPosition(LatLng latLng)
    {
        if (Google != null) Google.Position = latLng.Google;
        if (Huawei != null) Huawei.Position = latLng.Huawei;
    }
...
}
```

Right now i have this kind of implementation. The problem is that this is setting the Marker for both huawei and google. but what i really want is to have something more generic so that when i do `new Marker()` it will automaticly use google or huawei without setting both or need to pass a instance of both.

Comment: Why are you using two maps at the same time? You can choose one or the other.

Comment: Because of the huawei ban. the latest huawei dont have google play services. So i need to support both maps

Comment: In short, you need to use [OOP](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_oop.asp): declare abstract class e.g. `AbstractMap` with general methods declaration and implement your app functionality using it. Then, extend `AbstractMap` in classes `GoogleMapsMap` and `HuaweiMapsMap`. and once, on application start, check maps availability and instantiate `AbstractMap` as `GoogleMapsMap` or `HuaweiMapsMap.

Comment: yes, i ended up doing that